# How to transform an ndarray by an index mapping

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

How to transform an ndarray by an index mapping? For example,

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.arange(3*4).reshape((3,4))
>>> x
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
>>> wanted = np.array([[x[i, 1+i-2*j] if 1+i-2*j>=0 and 1+i-2*j<4 else 0 for j in range(4)] for i in range(3)])
>>> wanted
array([[ 1,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 6,  4,  0,  0],
       [11,  9,  0,  0]])
```

Can we do in a vectorized way (not by loops or list impression)? The list compression or loop is very slow on my sizeable ndarray.

Answer (score 0):

You can avert loops (and thereby list-comprehensions as well) by some simple indexing tricks.
A verbal description of the following code snippet would be:

1. Define column and row matrices
2. Calculate binary "condition" matrix
3. Define the linear-combination indexing that you want
4. Use combination of the indexing and the condition to calculate final output

In code -

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(3*4).reshape((3,4))
c_ = np.tile(np.arange(4), (3, 1))  # Step 1
r_ = np.tile(np.arange(3).reshape(3, 1), (1, 4))  # Step 1
condition = np.logical_and(1 + r_ - 2 * c_ >= 0, 1 + r_ - 2 * c_ < 4)  # Step 2
wanted = x[r_, (1 + r_ - 2 * c_) * condition] * condition  # Steps 3 and 4
print(wanted)
# [[ 1  0  0  0]
# [ 6  4  0  0]
# [11  9  0  0]]
```

(Note that when indexing `x`, you need to multiply the columns index-matrix by `condition` so that the linear combination doesn't overflow the `x.shape`. It doesn't matter that the values there are all taken from column 0, because we zero-out the output at those locations anyway).